# There is a way to do some kind of left join on CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

We have default documents that are created by the system but a user can "override" them. That´s means, create a copy of the document owned by "system". The result it´s a modified version of the document with the property "owner"="username".
The users can read only their own document and, if it´s does not exists, the system´s default.
So, the question: there is a way to _find documents using a selector or by using functions able to return system documents but,if there is a document defined by the user, this sould be returned instead of the system defaults.

The parametes to use for the query are: username and docname

The common document´s structure is:

{
  "_id": "...",
  "docname": "doc name",
  "owner": "System or username"
}

Answer (score -1):

As presented in the question, one can *mostly* achieve the desired outcome with a Mango index and query.

First, create an index for **owner** and **docname**

```
{
   "index": {
      "fields": [
         "docname",
         "owner"
      ]
   }
}
```

To query owner John Doe for "doc name 3",

```
{
   "selector": {
      "$and": [
         {
            "docname": "doc name 3"
         },
         {
            "owner": {
               "$or": [
                  "System",
                  "John Doe"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Assuming John Doe hasn't derived their own version of "doc name 3", the result would simply be the System document, for example

```
{
 "_id": "821985c5140ca583e108653fb6031665",
 "_rev": "3-6de569538ee2b96c3029b10dc052aa6d",
 "docname": "doc name 3",
 "owner": "System"
}
```

So far so good. If John Doe has derived their own version of "doc name 3", the result would be 2 rows:

```
{
 "_id": "821985c5140ca583e108653fb6031665",
 "_rev": "3-6de569538ee2b96c3029b10dc052aa6d",
 "docname": "doc name 3",
 "owner": "John Doe",
},
{
 "_id": "821985c5140ca583e108653fb6031665",
 "_rev": "3-6de569538ee2b96c3029b10dc052aa6d",
 "docname": "doc name 3",
 "owner": "System"
}
```

OK, well this is not so great because code has to pick the winner because if the owner is Zane Gray the System document would appear first (collation).

This is why I said *mostly* above because the **owner** field is problematic - "System" really gets in the way of user names.  A way around this problem is to specify a sort order on the owner field based on the user name as compared to System - but that's messy, yuck.

It would be ideal to zap the owner field away for System and use a number instead, say a field named **derived** with a value greater than 0 indicating a user document and zero indicating a System document.

Keeping things as presented so far but now assume a derived field is present in the documents. Add a new index for the derived field, with sort:

```
{
   "index": {
      "fields": [
         { "derived": "desc" }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now this Mango query

```
{
   "limit": 1,
   "selector": {
      "$and": [
         {
            "docname": "doc name 3"
         },
         {
            "owner": {
               "$or": [
                  "System",
                  "John Doe"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }       
}
```

Produces *either* the System document *or* the user derived version.

The key is having the default `"sort": "desc"`, which will always present derived documents first and as such `"limit": 1` provides a single document result; if a derived document for John Doe exists and the limit is set to 2, the result would be something akin to

```
{
 "_id": "821985c5140ca583e108653fb6031665",
 "_rev": "3-6de569538ee2b96c3029b10dc052aa6d",
 "docname": "doc name 3",
 "owner": "John Doe",
 "derived": 1
},
{
 "_id": "821985c5140ca583e108653fb602f396",
 "_rev": "3-34f29216b467fe21c65db3e4f1a638ac",
 "docname": "doc name 3",
 "owner": "System",
 "derived": 0
}
```

I used Fauxton+CouchDB 2.3 to check my work here.  CouchDB gurus might have a superior solution.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I´m using a similar aproach (the difference is that I´m using $in":[...] instead of "$or".
Sorting and using "limit it´s a good way to achieve the desired behaviour for 1 document use cases.
But the thing becomes more difficult when,for example, trying to list many documents, like all documents

Comment: Given your data there is no way to get the results you want with a Mango query without post-processing the results.  It can be done with a view, but would require  generating a one-to-one user -> system document, and leveraging the value field as outlined in the CouchDB documentation regarding [Joins with Views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html), and that solution would require maintenance.  Good luck!